# Изменение watermark itext 7

Tags: java, pdf, текст, itext

Необходимо с помощью библиотеки для JAVA iText 7 изменить Watermark (водный знак) на первой странице pdf файла, то есть имеется готовый pdf и в нем есть какой-то водный знак. Его необходимо или изменить (цвет,размер,положение) или по-хорошему вытащить и сохранить в txt файле.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Изменение существующего PDF-это тяжело. Если водяной знак представляет собой изображение, вы можете использовать iText для извлечения изображения, а затем изменить его (с помощью стандартного API в Java) и построить новый pdf-документ, используя существующие страницы и новый образ.
Есть несколько примеров водяных знаков на сайте iText. 
В целом я бы порекомендовал задать вопрос на англоязычном stackoverlow, так как мы обычно проверяем, что более часто.